# Grabbing Query from SubQuery in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have a problem with mysql query.

I am writing SQL query to get ID and Timestamp from tablebusiness with different query

```
SELECT `ID`,`TimeStamp`,pow(-6-`Latitude`,2)+pow(106-`Longitude`,2)*cos(-6*0.017453292519943)*cos(`Latitude`*0.017453292519943) as DistanceSquare FROM `tablebusiness` WHERE Title LIKE '%sushi%' AND -6.8996746410157 < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < -5.1003253589843 AND 105.10032535898 < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < 106.89967464102 ORDER BY DistanceSquare  LIMIT 2 ,20
```

Now this works fine in my case.

However I do not want DistanceSquare to be mentioned in the final result to save bandwidth. So I do

```
SELECT `ID`,`TimeStamp` FROM  (SELECT `ID`,`TimeStamp`,pow(-6-`Latitude`,2)+pow(106-`Longitude`,2)*cos(-6*0.017453292519943)*cos(`Latitude`*0.017453292519943) as DistanceSquare FROM `tablebusiness` WHERE Title LIKE '%sushi%' AND -6.8996746410157 < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < -5.1003253589843 AND 105.10032535898 < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < 106.89967464102 ORDER BY DistanceSquare  LIMIT 2 ,20)
```

So basically I am picking up ID and TimeStamp from a table generated by the inner SELECT. It doesn't work. How should I format it?

I only want to get ID and TimeStamp from tablebusiness

can any one help me to solve this problem?

Not a big one but I just want to learn.

This is the PhP code I used to generate this query

```
$phiper180=pi()/180;
$formula="pow(".$_GET['lat']."-`Latitude`,2)+pow(".$_GET['long']."-`Longitude`,2)*cos(".$_GET['lat']."*".$phiper180.")*cos(`Latitude`*".$phiper180.")";

$query="SELECT `ID`,`TimeStamp`,$formula as DistanceSquare FROM `tablebusiness` WHERE Title LIKE '%".$_GET['keyword']."%' AND ". ($_GET['lat']-$distanceindegrees). " < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < " . ($_GET['lat']+$distanceindegrees) . " AND " . ($_GET['long']-$distanceindegrees). " < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < " . ($_GET['long']+$distanceindegrees)." ORDER BY DistanceSquare  LIMIT ".($startFrom)." ,20";
$query="SELECT `ID`,`TimeStamp` FROM  (".$query.")";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't u just add (pow(-6-`Latitude`,2)+pow(106-`Longitude`,2)*cos(-6*0.017453292519943)*cos(`Latitude`*0.017453292519943)) in order by clause no need to use sub query for that. Try following:

```
SELECT `ID`,`TimeStamp` FROM `tablebusiness` WHERE Title LIKE '%sushi%' AND -6.8996746410157 < `Latitude` AND `Latitude` < -5.1003253589843 AND 105.10032535898 < `Longitude` AND `Longitude` < 106.89967464102 ORDER BY (pow(-6-`Latitude`,2)+pow(106-`Longitude`,2)*cos(-6*0.017453292519943)*cos(`Latitude`*0.017453292519943))  LIMIT 2 ,20
```

Comment: Ah works well. Works very well. Actually I've been thinking of doing this with stored procedure but there seems to be some several ways to do so.